# xcode remove custom navigation image in pickerview galley

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added the following code in the appDelegate to achieve custom background images for the navigation bar.

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav-Bar_01.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav-Bar_02_alter.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt];
```

However, I want to exclude the native gallery pickerView from this background.

Is there any way to do so without applying the background on each navigation bar alone, but keeping the same code in the appDelegate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up placing a background image for every navigation controller instead of placing it in the App Delegate. The background was then not applied on the pickerView.

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav-Bar_01"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```